# Get the nth commit/version from GIT local Repo

Tags: git, version

This is the Scenario

I have 5 version of my code in GIT.

```
Commit 1
Commit 2
Commit 3
Commit 4
Commit 5
```

Now I have a lot of uncommitted changes in the code. I want to get one of the earlier version (`say commit 3`) in a different physical location without losing the uncommitted changes.

In other words, while am working on the latest version, I want to give some one the earlier working version , without writing any changes to GIT repo.

*Please dont ask me, why did not I want to commit the changes.*

**Simplified version of my Question**

Can I do something like this in GIT??

```
svn export -r123 https://svnrepo C:/temp
```

Where 123 is the version and C:/Temp is the target location.
I believe this will not make changes to repository!

Comment: `clone` and `checkout` the specific commit

Comment: it is commited not push (I guess, otherwise there is nothing to it)

Comment: @OfirFarchy, pushing is not always necessary, you can clone any repository you have access to. Uncommitted changes are never cloned.

Comment: You are right, but he has commited but unpushed code he'd like to get back to!

Comment: @OfirFarchy not true, nowhere does it say that: "...in a different physical location" and "I want to give some one the earlier working version" make me think otherwise. Perhaps the OP is not being clear about what he'd really like to accomplish. I will not be surprised if he really just wants to `rebase`...

Comment: @soulseekah what does checkout do?? Will not it overwrite the existing one.. Bcoz I could not see a way to mention physical location in it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Just give someone a copy of your repository in a specific state?

Comment: @madhairsilence if so, you have to first `git clone` your repository to a new location then go to that location `git checkout` and do whatever is it that you're trying to do. Seems like an XY problem to me for now.

Comment: @soulseekah.. 
What exactly are you trying to do? - Yes. without interrupting my work

Comment: You just check it out as is, with all committed changes, if you want to avoid some later commits and clone up to a certain commit do tell. I'm still quite unaware of the issue you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be a missing feature in GIT. Just like 'export' in SVN. The only way is to check out the `nTh` version and then take it , and check out the master once again!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to *stash* your work away, and then get back to it later (without commiting the current changes).

Generally:

```
git stash
git checkout <commit>
- Do Something -
git stash apply
```

Read [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) for further information.

**EDIT:**
As @soulseekah pointed out, you can clone the **local** repository to some other location and the uncommited code will not clone.
And as for getting the nth commit (for example 3 commits ago):

```
git checkout HEAD~3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're really looking to simply get someone else to branch off and work on your repository, what you're probably looking for is a simple `git clone`. This will not force you to commit any of your working changes.

```
git clone /path/to/local/git-repo /path/to/local/new-git-repo
```

That will clone your repository without your pending changes. This will work both locally and remotely. Then the person wanting to start from a specific commit would get hold of that new clone and use `checkout -b`, `reset` or `rebase` (whichever is most appropriate to your flow).

As an example, here's what the other person would probably do after getting hold of your clone:

```
cd /path/to/new-git-repo
checkout -b new-feature commit-1
# work work work
# commit
```

Then you would `git pull /path/to/his/new-git/repo new-feature`, or maybe `fetch` and `cherry-pick` who knows.

In conclusion, it seems that you need a shared remote origin to avoid being confused by and doing the above, which would be the best way to solve your issue.

Comment: Version of what? You really need to describe the issue you're trying to solve exactly.

Comment: Once the other person gets hold of your repository, he would then `checkout`, or `rebase` or `reset` as mentioned above, if that's what you're referring to version. `git checkout -b Commit 1`... work work work ... `git commit` then you `pull` or he `push`es to a shared bare origin.